# Elastic Search 1.7 - Full Like search like SQL

Tags: elasticsearch

Im using old version of elastic search and I can't find a way to allow full like search like sql: '%%'

I have to search a non pre-known data so the "columns" are not known.

Ex. 
I have this columns ad an example of row:

```
source,dest,message
eth0, eth1, DELIVERY 3015801: SUCCESS: DID
```

In the search form, a user write something like this:

```
+message:"delivery"
or
+message:"delivery" and +source:"eht0"
```

The row is returned succesfully.
Unfortunally if they write:

```
+message:"success"
```

it return no row because of ":"

I need to allow user to write somethig like:

```
+message:"success*"
```

This is the query submitted. I have timerange filter and then the query :

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "from": 1561615860000,
                  "to": 1561619519000
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "+message:\"success\""
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to translate my text search in something like sql

```
message like 'success%'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is that an analyzed or a not-analyzed field? Maybe a [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) is what you want for that.

But generally:

- This version is more than dead. Please upgrade.
- This is not a relational database. If you try to translate the concepts 1:1 you will not get the most out of it. Documentation or courses will help you to move into proper search and away from `LIKE` searches.